# How to change name of a sheet while performing inner join

Tags: tableau

I need to join the same sheet (Airports) twice while performing inner join with Routes. First I inner join Routes (IATA of arrival flights) with IATA of airports in Airports. Unable to proceed with the next step.

[image]

Need to inner join once again Routes with Airports (matching IATA in Airports with departure IATA in Routes).

The final outcome should be as shown here (https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D58b0000BkAerHCQS/unable-to-inner-join-the-three-sheets):

[image]